# Can't align element with toStartOf in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Basically I have a `NumberPicker` aligned right, an `ImageView` aligned top left, and two buttons in a `LinearLayout` container that I am trying to align to the left of the Picker and bottom of the parent. No success. The container just takes up the whole space by overlapping the picker.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/cell_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/blue_light"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_tiny">

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/np_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_tiny"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_tiny" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/np_1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <Button
            style="@style/LargeHoloButton.SecondaryButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_tiny"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:text="@string/button.updown" />

        <Button
            style="@style/LargeHoloButton.SecondaryButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_tiny"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:text="@string/button.leftright" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from API level 17 you cannot use `layout_toStartOf`. You should use

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/np_1"
```

Again from API 17 you cannot use 'layout_alignParentEnd'. Instead use

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

And you have an error your relativelayout width is set to '0dp'. make it `match_ parent`.

The corrected code is below for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/cell_1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:background="#000099"
android:padding="8dp">

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/np_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/np_1"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/np_1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/np_1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <Button

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:text="assafsasaf" />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:text="sadsadsadsa" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And it looks like below image (set colour and padding as yours)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecKF6.png

Comment: The compiler tells me toLeftOf is the older/redundant attribute. Anyways, I added both ... API 17 ... the RelativeLayout's width is 0dp, with weight 1, because it is part of a TableRow. Needs weight to spread cells/cols evenly. Copy/pasted your code snippet, still isn't working.

Comment: As an independent view it works. if want to think its inside a table row than we need to see the whole view to make it correct. layouts are often dependent on each other

Comment: It's really annoying me. The problem seems to be elsewhere. When I copy the code, even with all the containers: TableLayout, ScrollView, etc, and paste in a new app, it works. I think the thing is, I am adding programmatically ids to the table elements, with setID(). Those ids probably collide with the np_1 id. I removed the np_1. But now, since I cannot use layout_toStartOf anymore, I have to add the rule programmatically like this:

Comment: `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_START, TableID.NUMBER_PICKER.getValue() + incrementID);
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, TableID.NUMBER_PICKER.getValue() + incrementID);`

Comment: Still isn't working. And when I add a rule to, let's say, the Picker, it IS working. Weird.

Comment: can you add an image with the question what you are trying to achieve? then i can see if there is any other approch you can follow @speirs23

Comment: I need to order an image, two buttons and a NumberPicker in a Table cell. Perhaps, I will do that, try a different approach, redesign the xml or something. I actually had it working fine initially, but my xml was 700-800+ lines, Table, 5-6 rows, 2 cols. So I decided to refactor, move a generic row in a separate xml, add with <include> each new row in the Table xml, then add ids to various elements programmatically.

Comment: Darn, it is RelativeLayout.START_OF, not RelativeLayout.ALIGN_START. I had also forgotten to remove all row xml IDs that will be duplicate in the table xml. Fixed it. Thanks for your assistance.:)